# Compare mongodb and biqquery data

Tags: mongodb, google-bigquery

I have one requirement, I need to compare mongodb and bigquery data, basically I have 2 json objects and I need to compare them and display matched and unmatched results...I need to compare all the nested objects and arrays and return results

example data
const obj1 = {
foo: 1,
bar: 2,
h: 1
};

const obj2 = {
a:{
bar: 2,
h:1
}
};

compare(obj1,obj2) //this should return below result

matched
{
bar:2,
h:1
}

I tried comparing 2 objects but It will not check for netsted objects and does not retunr difference.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm using nodejs

Comment: I need to compare 2 objects and it has to check for data in nested objects as well, for example 

I have 2 objects obj1 and obj2

obj1 = { foo: 1, bar: 2, h: 1 };

const obj2 = { a:{ bar: 2, h:1 } };

if I compare these 2 objects result should be 

matched { bar:2, h:1 }

so data which matches obj1's data is present in nested object (key->a)

so It has to check for nested objects as well, I tried so many ways but it is only checking key and values and not checking nested objects and arrays